# Pagination: Next/Previous related to author

Tags: pagination, relatedto, author, previous-next

I'm having trouble limiting next/previous links in one channel to articles by the author.

next/previous links are working correctly on the regular blog but when included on the DJ blog I get `unknown property errors` in the template.

If I remove the **merge** line below pagination appears to work, but includes DJ posts not by the current Dj.

url looks like `https://domain.com/djs/503/firstName-lastName` where 503 is the author.id

---

```
{# Set parameters for prev/next elements list #}
{% set params = craft.entries.section(channel).orderBy('title asc') %}

{# if djs channel limit to author based on url segment 2 which is author id #}
{% if craft.app.request.segment(1) == 'djs' %}
  {# get dj to relate and limit next/prev #}
  {% set author = craft.app.request.getSegment(2) %}
  {# {% set dj = craft.users.id(author).one() %} #}

  {# {% set params = craft.entries.section('djBlog').relatedTo(author).orderBy('title asc') %} #}

  {% set params = params | merge({ relatedTo: author }) %}

{% endif %}
```

Below code is working on all other templates except the DJ blog where I need to restrict pagination to posts by the current author. Only including here in case it may be relevant though I don't think so.

```
<div class="entry-pagination grid-container"> {# grid-container #}
  <div class="grid-x grid-padding-x">
    <div class="cell small-12 {% if backToPath == 'the-word-for-you-today' %}medium-12{% else %}medium-8 medium-offset-2{% endif %} next-prev">

      {% if prevEntry %}        
        <a href="{{ prevEntry.url }}" class="prev-blog">
          {#<img src="/assets/images/previous.png" alt="">#}
          {{ macros.icon("next", "icon-blue", "40", "40") }}
           Previous
        </a>
      {% else %}
        <a href="" class="prev-blog" disabled="true">
          {#<img src="/assets/images/previous.png" alt="">#}
          {{ macros.icon("next", "icon-blue", "40", "40") }}
           Previous
        </a>    
      {% endif %}

      {% if backTo == 'true' %}
        <a href="/{{ backToPath }}" class="button">
          Back to {{ backToTitle }}
          {# <img src="/assets/images/previous.png" alt=""> #}
        </a><!-- /.button -->
      {% endif %}


      {% if nextEntry %}
        <a href="{{ nextEntry.url }}" class="next-blog"><span>Next</span>{{ macros.icon("next", "icon-blue", "40", "40") }}</a>
      {% else %}
        <a href="" class="next-blog" disabled="true"><span>Next</span>{{ macros.icon("next", "icon-blue", "40", "40") }}</a>
      {% endif %}
    </div><!-- /.cell small-12 -->
  </div><!-- /.grid-x grid-padding-x -->
</div><!-- /.grid-container -->
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are trying to merge an object of type `ElementQuery` with an array so your object will be transformed as an array and merged with the new array. Of course you'll end up having an array instead of a query so you can't execute it in order to fetch the entries.

Instead of merging it, why not setting the parameter directly?

```
{% do param.authorId(author) %}
```

Furthermore authors are not related to entries  (except you set them in an additional field)

Comment: did not know about {% do blah %} thank you. That worked.